# How do I edit/access Chrome app properties on GNOME?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 20.04

In KDE or Windows, I can add `-disable-prompt-on-repost` when right-clicking the Chrome app & going to *properties* > *command*.

Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME does not show the target field/command. I only get the *general* and *permission* tab.
Is there a way to do that in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

1. Copy the Google Chrome launcher from the `/usr/share/applications/` folder to your `~/.local/share/applications/` folder. It should appear as a file with `.desktop` suffix.
2. Open the `.desktop` file with a text editor of your choice.
3. Look for the `Exec=` line. This line contains the command that is currently used to launch Google Chrome. Append the flag you want to add to this line (e.g. add  `-disable-prompt-on-repost` at the end of the `Exec=` line).
4. Save the file.